# jQuery error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using Chrome Developer Tools to debug a script. Its reporting the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
doColor                                         admin.php:292
$.get.theme                                     admin.php:159
f.extend._Deferred.e.resolveWith                jquery-1.6.1.min.js:16
w                                               jquery-1.6.1.min.js:18
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send.d           jquery-1.6.1.min.js:18
```

The code is:

```
$('#my_theme').change
(
    function() 
    {
    $("#largePreview").hide();
    var myImage = $('#my_theme :selected').text();
    $('.selectedImage img').attr('src','<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/styles/'+myImage+'/screenshot.jpg');
    $('.selectedImage img').attr('title',myImage);
    $.get('<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/color.php', {theme: myImage, spot: '1'}, function(data){doColor('#theme_header_color', data);});
    $.get('<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/color.php', {theme: myImage, spot: '2'}, function(data){doColor('#theme_sidebar_color', data);});
    $.get('<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/color.php', {theme: myImage, spot: '3'}, function(data){doColor('#theme_spot_color_alt', data);});
    $.get('<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/color.php', {theme: myImage, spot: '4'}, function(data){doColor('#theme_spot_color_alt2', data);});
    }
);




function doColor(el, color){
    $(el).val(color).trigger('keyup');
    $(el).attr('value', color);
    $(el).val(color)=color;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This

```
$(el).val(color)=color;
```

should just be

```
$(el).val(color);
```

Although I cannot say whether this is the only problem. You are actually already setting the color two statements earlier with `$(el).val(color).trigger('keyup');`.

`$(el).attr('value', color);` also seems to be unnecessary if you are using `val`. What are you trying to accomplish with these two lines?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(el).val(color)=color;
```

You can't assign like this, it is a DOM element.

```
$(el).val(color); # This will set the value of the el element to the value of color.
```